# flow flags null access only if prop is not typed

Tags: javascript, flowtype

These two objects are identical apart from the type annotations. Both initialize property `x` to null. The second is explicitly annotated to  be `null`. However, flow only reports an error on the `get()` method of the first object.

Why is this?

```
var obj1 = {
    x: null,
    get() {
        return this.x.a.b.c;
    }
};

var obj2: {
    x: null,
    get: () => number
} = {
    x: null,
    get() {
        return this.x.a.b.c;
    }
};

module.exports = function () {
    return obj1.get() + obj2.get();
};
```

The error, which is only on obj1.get, is

```
  return this.x.a.b.c;
                ^ property `a`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
  return this.x.a.b.c;
         ^^^^^^ null
```

I get the same result if `x` is typed as a union, like `null | number`.